# R: interpreting output of caret::train( ) with method glmStepAIC

Tags: r, logistic, aic, caret, importance

I am having trouble understanding the output of `caret::train( )` with `method = "glmStepAIC"`. Here is the sample code on the dataset `PimaIndiansDiabetes`. There are 8 predictor variables `insulin`, `age`, `pressure`, `pedigree`, `pregnant`, `mass`, `glucose`, `triceps`. The response variable is binary `diabetes`.

```
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

library(caret)
trControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          repeats = 3,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          number = 10, 
                          savePredictions = TRUE,
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

  caret_model <- train(diabetes~., 
                       data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, 
                       method="glmStepAIC", 
                       family = "binomial",
                       direction ="backward",
                       trControl=trControl)
```

The output I got is very long, an extract is here:

```
Start:  AIC=679.72
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
    mass + pedigree + age

           Df Deviance    AIC
- triceps   1   661.75 677.75
- insulin   1   662.17 678.17
<none>          661.72 679.72
- age       1   664.75 680.75
- pressure  1   669.92 685.92
- pedigree  1   670.43 686.43
- pregnant  1   673.20 689.20
- mass      1   695.17 711.17
- glucose   1   759.66 775.66

Step:  AIC=677.75
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + insulin + mass + pedigree + 
    age

           Df Deviance    AIC
- insulin   1   662.19 676.19
<none>          661.75 677.75
- age       1   664.75 678.75
- pressure  1   670.04 684.04
- pedigree  1   670.62 684.62
- pregnant  1   673.22 687.22
- mass      1   699.39 713.39
- glucose   1   761.45 775.45

Step:  AIC=676.19
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + mass + pedigree + 
    age

           Df Deviance    AIC
<none>          662.19 676.19
- age       1   665.53 677.53
- pressure  1   670.62 682.62
- pedigree  1   670.71 682.71
- pregnant  1   673.74 685.74
- mass      1   699.39 711.39
- glucose   1   768.91 780.91
Start:  AIC=644.26
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
    mass + pedigree + age

           Df Deviance    AIC
- triceps   1   626.39 642.39
- insulin   1   627.76 643.76
<none>          626.26 644.26
- age       1   628.72 644.72
- pressure  1   631.71 647.71
- pedigree  1   635.02 651.02
- pregnant  1   641.49 657.49
- mass      1   665.00 681.00
- glucose   1   740.27 756.27

Step:  AIC=642.39
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + insulin + mass + pedigree + 
    age

           Df Deviance    AIC
<none>          626.39 642.39
- insulin   1   628.67 642.67
- age       1   628.95 642.95
- pressure  1   632.33 646.33
- pedigree  1   635.04 649.04
- pregnant  1   641.55 655.55
- mass      1   668.08 682.08
- glucose   1   743.92 757.92
Start:  AIC=741.45
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + triceps + insulin + 
    mass + pedigree + age

           Df Deviance    AIC
- triceps   1   723.45 739.45
- insulin   1   725.19 741.19
<none>          723.45 741.45
- age       1   725.97 741.97
- pressure  1   729.99 745.99
- pedigree  1   733.78 749.78
- pregnant  1   738.68 754.68
- mass      1   764.22 780.22
- glucose   1   838.37 854.37

Step:  AIC=739.45
.outcome ~ pregnant + glucose + pressure + insulin + mass + pedigree + 
    age

           Df Deviance    AIC
<none>          723.45 739.45
- insulin   1   725.46 739.46
- age       1   725.97 739.97
- pressure  1   730.13 744.13
- pedigree  1   733.92 747.92
- pregnant  1   738.69 752.69
- mass      1   768.77 782.77
- glucose   1   840.87 854.87
```

I understand that if a predictor increases the AIC of the model, it should not be included in the model. From the output, how do I know what are the final list of variables that are kept? I can see that `triceps` is no longer at the bottom of the output, is it already discarded?

Furthermore, if I inspect variable importance using `varImp(caret_model)`. I see this :

```
ROC curve variable importance

         Importance
glucose     100.000
mass         59.818
age          59.567
pregnant     32.626
pedigree     27.306
pressure     19.418
triceps       6.299
insulin       0.000
```

Why is `insulin` the least important but it is still included in the model after training?

Comment: Also a side thought: Is it because I do 3-repeated 10-fold cross-validation that the output is super long?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use varImp on the your caret_model train object. If you inspect `getS3Method("varImp", "train")`, you'll see a check for a varImp method on the modelInfo, which doesn't exist for the `method = "glmStepAIC"`

To check the variable importance on your model, make a direct call:
`varImp(caret_model$finalModel)`

You'll see that triceps is not in the model and has already been excluded.

When the varImp method doesn't exist for something like "glmStepAIC", it looks at the initial training data which includes all features (including those that were thrown out earlier).